# Questions about the h.264 JM ldecod

Tags: c++, h.264

Now I'm doing the h.264 video decoding by JM's ldecod.
I would like to use ldecod to examine the syntax of video clip whose format is h.264, **and disable the function of the yuv frame store while doing video decoding**.

I have traced the source code of ldecod, but I cannot find the related code to disable the function of store yuv frame.

Could anyone give me some ideas?

Thanks a lot !!

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution for that after several experiments.
If you'd to disable the function of output pictures while doing h.264 decoding, you should trace following functions and step by step:

> exit_picture() -> store_picture_in_dpb() -> output_one_frame_from_dbp
>   -> **write_stored_frame()**

Then you can close the function of **write_stored_frame** to disable the frame output.